# Sharepoint Online add-in redirect after closing preview through Allitems.aspx

Tags: web-part, document, library, aspx, preview

I have written a sharepoint add-in that is more userfriendly to manage documents in a library. To make it easy for me im using Allitems.aspx together with an id to preview document.

```
https://doamin.sharepoint.com/teams/vlsdev/VLSdokument/Forms/AllItems.aspx?id=%2Fteams%2Fvlsdev%2FVLSdokument%2FdemoDoc.docx&parent=undefined
```

[image: preview]

The preview pops upp in a new tab. Problem is if the user uses the "close" button marked red, in the corner they arrive at the document library where i dont want normal users to be.

```
https://domain.sharepoint.com/teams/vlsdev/VLSdokument/Forms/AllItems.aspx?id=undefined
```

[image: document library]

Can i some how remove that close button? Redirect?

Or do i have to write my own custom preview in an iFrame?

Answer (score 0):

I understand from your scenario your goal is to preview the document from a SharePoint add-in you are building a URL which you can be used to open from a browser tab.

To achieve this scenario we have used 2 options. You can try and see is this what you are looking for

**Preview Document From Browser tab**

Syntax:

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + /_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=file guid&file=file name&action=default
```

Example

```
https://demo.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc={CA9C01CE-CB61-4F0E-903D-16BEB63C4C6E}&file=demo.docx&action=default
```

**Embed document in a page**

```
<iframe src='https://demo.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc={CA9C01CE-CB61-4F0E-903D-16BEB63C4C6E}&file=demo.docx&action=default&action=embedview&wdStartOn=1' width='476px' height='288px' frameborder='0'>This is an embedded <a target='_blank' href='https://office.com'>Microsoft Office</a> document, powered by <a target='_blank' href='https://office.com/webapps'>Office Online</a>.</iframe>
```

Either way works for us.

Comment: Yeah i have used WopiFram aswell but with the use of Allitems i get more built in sharepoint functionality in the preview, like open document in online/word, share, download, delete and so on. But maybe the way to go is custom with wopiframe.